# Tron smart contract TransferOwnership function error

Tags: transfer

I want to implement TransferOwnership function in already made tron smart contract but it keep throwing error whenever I want to compile the code. I guess 1 thing maybe I'm using an Owner modifier and did not define an owner anywhere in the contract.

Please can anyone show me how to define Owner. Thanks for helping me out.

```
function changeOwner(address payable _newOwner) public ownerOnly{
       owner = _newOwner;
    }
```

And this is the error message whenever I compiled it

```
Compiled error: [{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"contract.sol:378:5: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.\n function changeOwner(address payable _newOwner) public ownerOnly{\r\n ^------^\n","message":"Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.","severity":"error","sourceLocation":{"end":12928,"file":"contract.sol","start":12920},"type":"ParserError"}]
```

Comment: As the error-message tells you - Where is the contract declaration? Where is the compiler-version pragma?

Comment: Please can you give me a sample on how to declare it ? I'm not that good in solidity

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/

Comment: And you should by the least learn the basics of the language before jumping to implementing more complex functionality.

Comment: Okay, Thank you bro, Are you telegram or WhatsApp ?